# Parsing key-value pairs, selecting based on value, and creating new column with SQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a my_table like this. Col2 is a string type:

```
| Col1         | Col2                               |
|--------------|------------------------------------|
| some_string  |{siblings:0, pets:1, have_friends:0}|
| some_string  |{siblings:0, pets:0, have_friends:0}|
| some_string  |{siblings:1, pets:2, have_friends:3}|
| some_string  |{siblings:1, pets:1, have_friends:0}|
```

I would like to use SQL to parse the key:value pairs on Col2, and filter out pairs where the value is "0" so that the output is:

```
| Col1         | Col2                               |
|--------------|------------------------------------|
| some_string  |{pets:1}                            |
| some_string  |{}                                  |
| some_string  |{siblings:1, pets:2, have_friends:3}|
| some_string  |{siblings:1, pets:1}                |
```

Would someone help?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Redshift, which is based on PostgreSQL 8.0. I've added the tag to my post. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Why are you storing such data into a relational database in the first place? *Especially* a columnar database like Redshift? You lose the benefits you expected to get as all `Col2` values are different from each other and thus can't be stored in columnar form efficiently. That means higher disk usage, higher CPU and larger bills

Comment: The values look like JSON and [while Redshift does have JSON functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html), using them will be slow and force Redshift to scan all rows. The linked docs explicitly say to use JSON sparingly and point to [the SUPER data type for semistructured data like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-overview.html). It's probably easier to clean up the data before insertion though

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not have the privilege to make that decision :)

Comment: You can't change how Redshift works, so either the team decides to use Redshift properly or you get to explain to management the large you'll get when expensive Redshift operations are used to do what should be cheap ETL work.

Comment: BTW what's the *actual* format of the text? Is it JSON or not? If not, you'll have to write some pretty complex parsing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's create the schema:

```
create table mytable(col1 text, col2 text);

insert into mytable(col1, col2)
values
('some_string', '{key1:0, key2:1, key3:0}'),
('some_string', '{key1:0, key2:0, key3:0}'),
('some_string', '{key1:1, key2:2, key3:3}'),
('some_string', '{key1:1, key2:1, key3:0}');
```

In order to compute the values you desire, use

```
select col2 as input, regexp_replace(col2, '(, )?key\d:0(, )?', '', 'g') as output
from mytable;
```

if you want to select them. `regexp_replace` replaces the match in a string (param1) of a pattern (param2) with a new string (param3). The `g` specifies that all matches are to be replaced.

Fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/omvF3XLrmCpYM79YYTA1wH/0

And if you need to update the values, then you can:

```
update mytable
set col2 = regexp_replace(col2, '(, )?key\d:0(, )?', '', 'g');
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/omvF3XLrmCpYM79YYTA1wH/1

EDIT

You can enhance the regex of the patter in the way you prefer. If you are to support any characters that are lower or upper case as well as numbers and underscore, try:

```
select col2 as input, regexp_replace(col2, '(, )?[a-z_A-Z0-9]*:0(, )?', '', 'g') as output
from mytable;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/omvF3XLrmCpYM79YYTA1wH/2

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works if my key is "key#". But they actually can be totally different words such as "apple", "orange", "green_pear". I'll update my post. Thank you so much!

Comment: @puifais understood. Enhanced the regex and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to remove the ", 'g'" part, and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can take using `Redshift` SQL:

1. Use string functions to split Col2 into its component key-value pairs.
2. Filter out the pairs with a value of "0".
3. Reconstruct the string in the JSON-like format.

This is a bit complex because Redshift doesn't support dynamic string parsing into columns or rows as easily as newer SQL databases. Typically, you'd handle such data in the application layer or use a database with JSON processing capabilities.

```
SELECT Col1,
       '{' || LISTAGG(Case When part_value != '0' Then part_key || ':' || part_value End, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY part_key) || '}' AS Col2
FROM (
    SELECT Col1,
           SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(Col2, ',', n.n), ':', 1) AS part_key,
           SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(Col2, ',', n.n), ':', 2) AS part_value
    FROM my_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) n 
    WHERE Col2 LIKE '%:%' 
) sub
GROUP BY Col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Redshift is a Postgres-based data warehouse This query might be working for you.

Initially, we plit the Col2 into key-value pairs, then filter out elements that have a value of 0, and finally, we rebuild Col2 :

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT Col1, Col2, value as Col2_splitted
   FROM my_table
   CROSS JOIN JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(('["' || replace( TRANSLATE(Col2, '{ }', ''), ',', '", "' ) || '"]')::json)
)
SELECT Col1, Col2, '{' || STRING_AGG(col2_splitted, ', ') || '}' AS Col2_filtered
FROM cte
WHERE split_part(col2_splitted, ':', 2) <> '0'
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, '{}'
FROM cte
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN split_part(col2_splitted, ':', 2) <> '0' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

The equivalent of `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT` on PostgreSql is `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT`.

Results :

```
col1        col2                        col2_filtered
some_string {key1:0, key2:1, key3:0}    {key2:1}
some_string {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3}    {key1:1, key2:2, key3:3}
some_string {key1:1, key2:1, key3:0}    {key1:1, key2:1}
some_string {key1:0, key2:0, key3:0}    {}
```

[Demo on PostgreSql](https://dbfiddle.uk/YGSFIhKU)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It seems to dislike unnest function:  `Undefined function: UNNEST. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function`

Comment: I have Included an equivalent of UNNEST, Please have a look